# Java method in React form

Tags: reactjs, spring, jpa

I've made a simple Spring JPA application. For inputed String "city" app looking for population information and then show it. In React i've made frontend - the simlest form containing text field for input and another for result. For now i don't know how to connect each other. I want to make a text field input in React to sent an argument to Java method and show the result of method operation in field 'result'. I've added 3 JS components and 4 Java class below. I assume that it have to be a few lines in JS code, so i would be appreciate for Your help.

```
    class App extends Component {
  render (){
  return(
    <div className='App'>
  <Form />
 <Result />
 </div>
  );
}
}
```

```
const Form = () => {
    return (
        <form>
            <input type='text'/>
            <button>Wyszukaj miasto</button>
        </form>

    )
}

export default Form;
```

```
const Result = () => {

    return (
        <div>Populacja</div>
    );
}

export default Result;
```

```
mport lombok.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString


public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int ID;
    String name;
    @Transient
    String CountryCode;
    String District;
    int Population;

    public City()
    {

    }

    public City(int ID, String name, /*String countryCode,*/ String District, int Population) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        /*this.CountryCode = countryCode;*/
        this.District = District;
        this.Population = Population;
    }
}
```

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Long> {

    List<City> findByName(String name);
    List<City> findByPopulation(int population);

}
```

```
@RestController
public class CityService {

    @Autowired
    CityRepository cityRepository;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

     @PostMapping("/cities")
    public ResponseEntity findCity(@RequestBody City city){
        List <City> foundedCity = cityRepository.findByName(city.getName());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(foundedCity);
    }

}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the query in `CityRepository`

```
    @Query("SELECT c.* FROM City c WHERE c.name LIKE %:name%")
    List<City> findByName(@Param("name") String name);

    @Query("SELECT c.* FROM City c WHERE c.Population=:population")
    List<City> findByPopulation(@Param("population") int population);
```

, And check the React part to make sure you are sending a `POST` request to URL `/cities` with a city JSON object

Comment: I am almost sure that Java code looks like it have to and JS code need some adds.